# Retrieving the node with more authors with published papers in the Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following script in the Neo4J

```
 CREATE (PaperA:Paper {title:'User Experience of Mobile Augmented
 Reality: A Review of Studies'}) CREATE (Irshad:Autor {name:'S.
 Irshad'}) CREATE (Rambli:Autor {name:'D. Rohaya Bt Awang Rambli'})

 CREATE(PaperB:Paper {title:'Quality of Experience in the Multimedia
 Internet of Things: definition and practical use cases'})
 CREATE(Floris:Autor {name:'A. Floris'}) CREATE(Atzori:Autor {name:'L.
 Atzori'})

 CREATE(PaperC:Paper {title:'What Changes from Ubiquitous Computing to
 Internet of Things in Interaction Evaluation?'}) CREATE(Andrade:Autor
 {name:'Andrade, R. M.'}) CREATE(Carvalho:Autor {name:'Carvalho, R.
 M.'}) CREATE(deAraújo:Autor {name:'de Araújo, I. L.'})
 CREATE(Oliveira:Autor {name:'Oliveira, K. M.'}) CREATE(Maia:Autor
 {name:'Maia, M. E'})


 CREATE(PaperD:Paper {title:'A QoE-aware Approach for Smart Home Energy
 Management'}) CREATE(Meloni:Autor {name:'Meloni, A'})
 CREATE(Pilloni:Autor {name:'Pilloni, V.'})

 (Irshad)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperA), (Rambli)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperA),
 (Floris)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperB), (Floris)- [:IS_AUTHOR] -> (PaperD),
 (Floris)- [:IS_AUTHOR] -> (PaperH), (Atzori)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperB),
 (Atzori)- [:IS_AUTHOR] -> (PaperD), (Atzori)- [:IS_AUTHOR] ->
 (PaperH), (Meloni)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperD),
 (Pilloni)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperD), (Andrade)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperC),
 (Carvalho)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperC), (deAraújo)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperC),
 (Oliveira)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperC), (Maia)-[:IS_AUTHOR]->(PaperC),
```

I´d like a script which return the authors with more published papers, which, in this case is Floris and Atzori. I am using the Neo4J 3.0.8 version.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello @gPxl. I have edited my answer to remove a not necessary `WITH` clause.

Comment: Hi, @BrunoPeres, I am still having the message: WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH (line 156, column 1 (offset: 6405))
"MATCH(a:Autor)-[r:IS_AUTHOR]->(:Paper)"
 ^

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Edited to answer correctly the requirements of the question:

```
// First step: getting the greatest number of publications by author
MATCH(author:Autor)-[r:IS_AUTHOR]->(:Paper)
WITH author, count(r) as count
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1
// Second step: getting all author who have number
// of publications equals to `count`
MATCH (a:Autor)-[r:IS_AUTHOR]->(p:Paper)
WITH a, count, count(r) AS r WHERE r = count
RETURN a
```

The output will be:

```
╒════════════════════╕
│"a"                 │
╞════════════════════╡
│{"name":"A. Floris"}│
├────────────────────┤
│{"name":"L. Atzori"}│
└────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the following message "WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH (line 155, column 1 (offset: 6404))
"MATCH(author:Autor)-[r:IS_AUTHOR]->(:Paper)"
 ^"

Comment: @gPxl This is because you are running the query in the same script that creates your initial data set. If you ran the query posted in this answer separately all will works.

Comment: thank you very much! It's working! Why I have separate the queries?

Comment: @gPxl I think you are coping and pasting the query answered here in the end of another script. I can suppose this based on the line the error occurs (line 156). It's related to the rules of Cypher grammar. If you really need ran this query after the script that creates your sample data set you can do `WITH *
MATCH(author:Autor)-[r:IS_AUTHOR]->(:Paper)
RETURN author, count(r) as count
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1`

Comment: @gPxl that is: put a `WITH *` before the `MATCH`.

Comment: I got it. Have a nice week...  Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155842/discussion-between-gpxl-and-bruno-peres).